# drag and drop files into a exe java

Tags: java

I want to build a java program that will take a python file and drop it into a .exe, thus starting that .exe and running the python file in it.

I have converted the whole python library into a .exe and I have build a boot system on it that just needs the python file to be dropped onto it. I have made this file so I can run python on PCs that don't have python installed. I would go with the .BAT method but so 32 bit systems have a hard time with batch drag and drop.

So I am asking for some code that would allow me to take a file and run it through another file. I hope this is the information you needed, if you need any more i will answer it!

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to get Java to "drag and drop" a file onto an `.exe` file. Most operating systems implement that as running the program with the filename as an argument. Are you trying to get Java to run an external program with a filename as an argument? If so, you're looking for the Java [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When posting questions, please keep in mind that breaking a long question into separate paragraphs is a lot easier to read than one big block of text.

Comment: no, im trying to run a python file through a exe that will allow it to execute. im not trying to create a progress, its just a one time thing.

Comment: yup worked great, thanks! just what i was looking for! :D